# Can I exclude an individual test from @BeforeEach using TestInfo interface?

Tags: java, junit5

I have been looking for ways to exclude an individual test from @BeforeEach. It was suggested to me in my previous question to use TestInfo Interface:
[Can I exclude an individual test from @BeforeEach in JUnit5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772186/can-i-exclude-an-individual-test-from-beforeeach-in-junit5)

I am very interested in this kind of solution. However I tried that and it did not work for me. Is it possible to do it that way? Am I doing anything wrong in my code?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockTest {

int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;

@BeforeEach
void init(TestInfo info) {
    if (info.getDisplayName().equals("testTwo"))
        return;

    a=5;
    b=10;
    c=15;
}

@Test
void testOne(){
    int expected = 15;
    assertEquals(expected,a+b);
}

@Test
void testTwo(){
    int expected = 3;
    assertEquals(expected,a+b+c);
}
}
```

The output for testTwo():

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
```

Expected :3
Actual   :30

```
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:54)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:195)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:152)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:327)
at rest.demo.controller.MockTest.testTwo(MockTest.java:40)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of info.getDisplayName() either using a debugger or a print statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a hack-approach to attempt individual exclusion. Why not use @Nested?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockTest {

  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  int c = 1;

  @Nested
  class InitializedTests{
    @BeforeEach
    void init(TestInfo info) {
        a=5;
        b=10;
        c=15;
    }

    @Test
    void testOne(){
        int expected = 15;
        assertEquals(expected,a+b);
    }

  }

  @Nested
  class StandaloneTests {
    @Test
    void testTwo(){
        int expected = 3;
        assertEquals(expected,a+b+c);
    }
  }
}
```